# Writing a short list in text file

Tags: python, list

I know to write a list into a text file, I can use for loop to go through it and write into f, or i can join the the list then write. But for example, if I have the following list

```
list = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
```

and I would like to save it in text file in this way

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F"
```

What would be the most beautiful/simplest/elegant way to do it please?

Comment: Maybe you want [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: This works: `print( ",".join( repr(x) for x in list ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with no libraries like this:

```py
lst = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]

with open(r"file.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write('"' + '","'.join(lst) + '"')
```

Or with [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```py
import json

lst = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]

json.dump(lst, "file.txt")
```

but that writes `["A","B","C","D","E","F"]` to the file (with the brackets).

Also you can do this:

```py
lst = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]

with open(r"file.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(lst))
```

but that writes `['A','B','C','D','E','F']` to the file (with the brackets). If you want it without the brackets, do `f.write(str(lst)[1:-1])` to cut off the brackets.

Comment: This is definitely the most beautiful way to do this, Thank you for your excellent answer!
with open(r"file.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write('"' + '","'.join(lst) + '"')

Comment: Actually, can you please explain why this script doesn't require a for loop?

Comment: @Victor I'm not the one who wrote this answer, but why would it?

Comment: Also, that first `.join()` etc. can be replaced by `repr()`, I think.

Comment: @AMC I added your solution to the answer, but `str` instead of `repr`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you have python 3.6 or higher you can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```
L = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
list_string = ",".join(f'"{i}"' for i in L)

with open("example.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(list_string)
```

example.txt contains:

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it would be better to do it without a for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use join

```
s= ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]

listToStr = ','.join(["\""+ str(elem)+"\"" for elem in s]) 

print(listToStr)
```

To write in file

```
with open("out.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(listToStr)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it would be better to do it without a for loop